# Rails: Repeating unit test - DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, tdd, dry

Is there any standard practice to DRY-out the repeating unit test cases in rails. For e.g. I have many models with the "name" attribute, I want to do same kind of unit tests for each model. I vaguely see that i need to create modules are reuse? Is that possible/correct?

Any pointers/practice to creating DRY unit test?

**Example code:** I want to do same kind of testing for many other models with the same named attribute.

```
require 'test_helper'


# Factory class
class UserFactory

  # Creates a valid template user
  def self.create
    user = User.new do |u|
      u.name = "Test User #{rand}"
      u.notes = "test notes"
    end
    user
  end

end

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # ------------
  # Init
  # ------------

  def setup
    @valid_usr = UserFactory.create
  end

  def teardown
    @valid_usr.destroy if @valid_usr.persisted?
    @valid_usr = nil
  end


  # ------------
  # Name
  # ------------

  test "should not have a dummy user object" do
    user = User.new
    assert !user.save
  end

  test "unique user name must be saved" do
    assert UserFactory.create.save!, "First entry must be saved"

    user = UserFactory.create
    user.name = "Different name"
    assert user.save!, "Unique user must be saved"
    user.destroy
  end

  test "non unique user names must not be saved" do
    user1 = UserFactory.create
    user2 = UserFactory.create
    user1.name = "Same User name"
    user2.name = "Same User name"

    assert user1.save!, "First entry must be saved"
    assert !user2.save, "Duplicate name should not be saved"

    user1.destroy
    user2.destroy
  end

  test "should not have user without a valid name" do
    # Invalid name
    @valid_usr.name = " "
    assert !@valid_usr.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the duplicate code in a module and include it in the actual test (as in, the class).

Comment: It works fine! However i am looking to parametrize the modules as next step. Do you have any ideas there?

Comment: I imagine you can hack something with method_missing, but I wouldn't use any sort of magic for tests. Perhaps you're better off using RSpec.

Comment: Does Rspec allows better ways to write DRY test cases? Any examples/posts will be useful.

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group